# What is advantage of using GMainLoop from glib.h rather than "while(true);" in C++ linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, glib

I have come across a code where they needed an infinite loop & they used

```
    GMainLoop *mainloop = NULL;

    mainloop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run (mainloop);
```

I have doubt why don't they use `while(true);` for same purpose. What does GMainLoop internally do, Ain't it will be same internally. How does `GMainLoop`  enhances the performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`g_main_loop` means the main event loop in glib. It is not just an infinite loop; it polls event sources, queues events it gets from them, and invokes event handlers. It also doesn't do that busily; that is to say, it'll not go to 100% CPU usage when nothing is happening (unless an event source is broken).

There's a description of it in [the glib documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html).